# boundingClientRect to get position of element relative to document

Tags: elm

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop program, using `boundingClientRect` from the DOM package to get the dimensions of the element to be moved, and `position` from the Mouse to track the movement of the mouse when dragging.

The program works fine before I have scrolled, but when I scroll down, the dragging element appears higher in the view than before I clicked it. What I suspect is happening is, `boundingClientRect` gets the position of the element relative to the viewpoint, and then I use those values to set the `top` and `left` values. However, `top` and `left` are relative to the document or to a parent element. However, I have no idea what I could use instead of or in addition to `boundingClientRect` to get the `left` and `top` values relative to the document or parent element.

Here's the code, it's probably clearer than my rambling.

```
type alias Model =
    { movableItemsList : List Item
    , originalMovableItems : List Item
    , movingItem : Maybe ( Item, Rectangle )
    , receivingItemsList : List Item
    , updatedItemsList : List ( Item, Rectangle )
    , drag : Maybe Drag
    , scrollTop : Float
    }

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        DragAndDelete deleteMsg xy movingItem movingRectangle ->
            model
                ! [ command (DragStart xy movingItem movingRectangle)
                  , command (deleteMsg movingItem)
                  ]

        DragStart xy selectedItem movingRectangle ->
            let
                movingItem =
                    List.head (List.filter (\i -> i.id == selectedItem.id) model.originalMovableItems)
                        |> Maybe.withDefault (Item "" "" 0 "")
            in
                { model
                    | drag = Just (Drag xy xy)
                    , movingItem = Just ( movingItem, movingRectangle )
                }
                    ! []

        DragAt xy ->
            { model
                | drag =
                    (Maybe.map (\{ start } -> Drag start xy) model.drag)
            }
                ! []

        DragEnd _ ->
            { model
                | movingItem = Nothing
                , drag = Nothing
            }
                ! []

        DeleteFromUpdatedList movingItem ->
            let
                isKeepable iteratingItem =
                    iteratingItem.id /= movingItem.id

                updatedItemsData =
                    List.filter (\( i, _ ) -> isKeepable i) model.updatedItemsList
            in
                { model
                    | updatedItemsList = updatedItemsData
                }
                    ! []

        DeleteFromMovableList movingItem ->
            let
                isKeepable iteratingItem =
                    iteratingItem.id /= movingItem.id

                movableItemsData =
                    List.filter isKeepable model.movableItemsList
            in
                { model
                    | movableItemsList = movableItemsData
                }
                    ! []

        UpdateReceivingItemsOnOverlap receivingRectangle receivingItem ->
            let
                receivingItemsData =
                    if (checkOverlap (getCurrentMovingRectangle model) receivingRectangle) then
                        List.map (\i -> updateItemColor i receivingItem) model.receivingItemsList
                    else
                        model.receivingItemsList
            in
                { model | receivingItemsList = receivingItemsData } ! []

        RestoreReceivingItemsListColor _ ->
            let
                receivingItemsData =
                    List.map restoreReceivingItemColor model.receivingItemsList
            in
                { model | receivingItemsList = receivingItemsData } ! []

        AddValues receivingRectangle receivingItem ->
            let
                movingItem =
                    movingItemMaybe model.movingItem

                updatedItemsData =
                    if (checkOverlap (getCurrentMovingRectangle model) receivingRectangle) then
                        ( { movingItem
                            | value = receivingItem.value + movingItem.value
                            , color = "#1A6B0D"
                          }
                        , receivingRectangle
                        )
                            :: model.updatedItemsList
                    else
                        model.updatedItemsList
            in
                { model
                    | updatedItemsList = updatedItemsData
                }
                    ! [ command (DeleteFromMovableList movingItem)
                      ]

        RestoreListContent ->
            let
                movingItem =
                    movingItemMaybe model.movingItem

                listItems =
                    movingItem :: model.movableItemsList
            in
                { model | movableItemsList = listItems } ! []


getCurrentMovingRectangle : Model -> Rectangle
getCurrentMovingRectangle model =
    let
        movingItemTuple =
            Maybe.withDefault ( Item "" "" 0 "0", Rectangle 0 0 0 0 ) model.movingItem

        ( _, movingRect ) =
            movingItemTuple
    in
        case model.drag of
            Nothing ->
                movingRect

            Just { start, current } ->
                Rectangle
                    (movingRect.top + toFloat (current.y - start.y))
                    (movingRect.left + toFloat (current.x - start.x))
                    (movingRect.width)
                    (movingRect.height)



-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div
        []
        [ receivingAndUpdatedItemsLayersDiv model
        , movableItemsListDiv model
        , if model.movingItem /= Nothing then
            movingItemDiv model
          else
            div [] []
        ]


receivingAndUpdatedItemsLayersDiv : Model -> Html Msg
receivingAndUpdatedItemsLayersDiv model =
    div
        [ style [ ( "position", "relative" ) ] ]
        [ div
            [ style
                [ ( "position", "relative" )
                , ( "top", "10px" )
                , ( "left", "80px" )
                ]
            ]
            [ div
                [ style
                    [ ( "z-index", "3" )
                    , ( "position", "absolute" )
                    ]
                , attribute "class" "drag-here-overlay"
                ]
                (List.map receivingItemOverlay model.receivingItemsList)
            , div
                [ style
                    [ ( "z-index", "0" )
                    , ( "position", "absolute" )
                    ]
                , attribute "class" "drag-here-underlay"
                ]
                (List.map receivingItemUnderlay model.receivingItemsList)
            ]
        , div
            []
            [ div
                [ style
                    [ ( "position", "absolute" )
                    , ( "z-index", "1" )
                    ]
                , attribute "class" "drag-here-updated"
                ]
                (List.map updatedItemUnderlay model.updatedItemsList)
            , div
                [ style
                    [ ( "position", "absolute" )
                    , ( "z-index", "4" )
                    ]
                ]
                (List.map updatedItemOverlay model.updatedItemsList)
            ]
        ]


movableItemsListDiv : Model -> Html Msg
movableItemsListDiv model =
    div
        [ style
            [ ( "position", "relative" )
            , ( "top", "10px" )
            , ( "left", "800px" )
            ]
        ]
        (List.map movableItemDiv model.movableItemsList)


updatedItemUnderlay : ( Item, Rectangle ) -> Html Msg
updatedItemUnderlay ( item, rectangle ) =
    div
        [ attribute "class" "drag-here-updated-underlay-item"
        , sharedStyles
        , style
            [ ( "background-color", item.color )
            , ( "border", "1px solid #000" )
            , ( "position", "absolute" )
            , ( "left", px rectangle.left )
            , ( "top", px rectangle.top )
            ]
        ]
        [ text item.text
        , br [] []
        , text (toString item.value)
        ]


updatedItemOverlay : ( Item, Rectangle ) -> Html Msg
updatedItemOverlay ( item, rectangle ) =
    div
        [ onDragStart DeleteFromUpdatedList item
        , attribute "class" "drag-here-updated-overlay-item"
        , sharedStyles
        , style
            [ ( "background-color", "transparent" )
            , ( "position", "absolute" )
            , ( "left", px rectangle.left )
            , ( "top", px rectangle.top )
            ]
        ]
        []


receivingItemUnderlay : Item -> Html Msg
receivingItemUnderlay item =
    div
        [ attribute "class" "drag-here-underlay-item"
        , sharedStyles
        , style
            [ ( "background-color", item.color )
              -- , ( "border", "1px solid #1A6B0D" )
            ]
        ]
        [ text item.text
        , br [] []
        , text (toString item.value)
        ]


receivingItemOverlay : Item -> Html Msg
receivingItemOverlay item =
    div
        [ on "mouseenter" (Decode.map (\d -> UpdateReceivingItemsOnOverlap d item) (DOM.target DOM.boundingClientRect))
        , on "mouseleave" (Decode.map (\d -> RestoreReceivingItemsListColor d) (DOM.target DOM.boundingClientRect))
        , on "mouseup" (Decode.map (\d -> AddValues d item) (DOM.target DOM.boundingClientRect))
        , attribute "class" "drag-here-overlay-item"
        , sharedStyles
        , style
            [ ( "background-color", "transparent" ) ]
        ]
        []


movableItemDiv : Item -> Html Msg
movableItemDiv item =
    div
        [ onDragStart DeleteFromMovableList item
        , attribute "id" ("drag-me " ++ toString item.value)
        , sharedStyles
        , style
            [ ( "background-color", item.color )
            , ( "border", "1px solid #DD0848" )
            , ( "position", "relative" )
            ]
        ]
        [ text "Drag Me!"
        , br [] []
        , text (toString item.value)
        ]


movingItemDiv : Model -> Html Msg
movingItemDiv model =
    let
        movingItem =
            movingItemMaybe model.movingItem

        realRectangle =
            getCurrentMovingRectangle model
    in
        div
            [ onMouseUp RestoreListContent
            , sharedStyles
            , style
                [ ( "background-color", "#FF3C8C" )
                , ( "border", "1px solid #DD0848" )
                , ( "position", "absolute" )
                , ( "top", px (realRectangle.top) )
                , ( "left", px (realRectangle.left) )
                , ( "z-index", "2" )
                ]
            ]
            [ text movingItem.text
            , br [] []
            , text (toString movingItem.value)
            ]


sharedStyles : Attribute a
sharedStyles =
    style
        [ ( "width", "100px" )
        , ( "height", "100px" )
        , ( "border-radius", "4px" )
        , ( "color", "white" )
        , ( "justify-content", "center" )
        , ( "align-items", "center" )
        , ( "display", "flex" )
        ]


onDragStart : (Item -> Msg) -> Item -> Attribute Msg
onDragStart deleteMsg item =
    on "mousedown"
        (Mouse.position
            `Decode.andThen`
                (\posit ->
                    DOM.target DOM.boundingClientRect
                        `Decode.andThen`
                            (\rect ->
                                Decode.succeed (DragAndDelete deleteMsg posit item rect)
                            )
                )
        )


px : countable -> String
px number =
    toString number ++ "px"
```

So, as you can see, when one clicks a `movableItemDiv`, the model's `drag` and `movingItem` fields are updated with the position of the mouse and the dimensions (Rectangle) of the `movableItem` respectively. However, these dimensions are relative to the viewpoint. `movingItemDiv` then calls `getCurrentMovingRectangle`, which sets the `left` and `top` styles of `movingItemDiv` according to the dimensions of the `movingItem` and the `drag` in the model. Because the dimensions of the `movingItem` are based on dimensions of the `movableItemDiv` relative to the viewpoint, not relative to the document, while the values set for the `top` and `left` values of the `movingItemDiv` establish the position of the element relative to the document (or the parent element, I'm not sure to be honest), the `movingItemDiv` is not positioned correctly. I hope this is clear!

Comment: You are probably using the [debois/elm-dom](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/debois/elm-dom/1.2.2/DOM) package. As explained [here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/debois/elm-dom/1.2.2/DOM#boundingClientRect), `boundingClientRect` is an approximation and does not work properly when scrolling.

Comment: And what does work properly when scrolling :-D ?

Comment: An alternative approach could be to use absolute positioning on the moving items. like in the [mouse drag](http://elm-lang.org/examples/drag) example, and use [this function from elm-lang/dom](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/dom/1.1.0/Dom-Scroll#y) to compensate for the scrolling when finding out if your moving item is over the intended target.

Comment: Personally, I have used drag-and-drop in elm only within the same container - so no dropping the item somewhere outside the scrolling area. E.g. in rearranging items vertically in a scrollable list (only allowing vertical drag).

Comment: In this example, the initial position is defined in the model. In the final version of this project, this list of movable items will come from a backend application, so I can't manually give each of them a position in the model.

Answer (score 2):

Updated to elm-0.18

Below is a quick and dirty example of a list with draggable items

(which you can copy to [elm-lang.org/try](http://elm-lang.org/try) to see it in action)

- each item has a relative positioning
- `transform: translate()` is used to position the item being dragged
- we do not know the absolute position of the item, but we do know how much it has moved relative to its (unknown) starting position.

Next step would be to determine if we are over a drop-zone when drag ends.
To calculate, you would need to know:

- the relative position of your drop zones compared to the top-left corner of your list container
- the size (width, height) of each drop zone
- the original position of the item being dragged relative to top-left of the list container

  - for that, you would need to know the actual height of each item (I always used a fixed height on each item)
- the amount of scroll in the list container (using Dom.y from elm-lang/dom)

Hope this will help you in the right direction!

```elm
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (on)
import Json.Decode as Json
import Mouse exposing (Position)



main =
  Html.program
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }


-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { position : Position
    , items : List String
    , drag : Maybe Drag
    }


type alias Drag =
    { id : Int
    , start : Position
    , current : Position
    }


init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
  Model 
    (Position 200 200)
    [ "Apples", "Bananas", "Cherries", "Dades" ]
    Nothing
  ! []



-- UPDATE


type Msg
    = DragStart Int Position
    | DragAt Position
    | DragEnd Position


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
  ( updateHelp msg model, Cmd.none )


updateHelp : Msg -> Model -> Model
updateHelp msg ({position, items, drag} as model) =
  case msg of
    DragStart id xy ->
      Model position items (Just (Drag id xy xy))

    DragAt xy ->
      Model position items (Maybe.map (\{id, start} -> Drag id start xy) drag)

    DragEnd _ ->
      Model position items Nothing



-- SUBSCRIPTIONS


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
  case model.drag of
    Nothing ->
      Sub.none

    Just _ ->
      Sub.batch [ Mouse.moves DragAt, Mouse.ups DragEnd ]



-- VIEW


(=>) = (,)

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    <| List.indexedMap (itemView model) model.items


itemView : Model -> Int -> String -> Html Msg
itemView model index item =
  let
    zIndex =
      case model.drag of
        Just {id} ->
          if index == id then
            "99"
          else
            "0"
        Nothing ->
          "0"
  in
    div
      [ onMouseDown index
      , style
          [ "background-color" => "#3C8D2F"
          , "border" => "2px solid orange"
          , "cursor" => "move"
          , "position"=> "relative"
          , "transform" => (getOffset model index)
          , "z-index" => zIndex
          , "width" => "100px"
          , "height" => "100px"
          , "border-radius" => "4px"
          , "color" => "white"
          , "display" => "flex"
          , "align-items" => "center"
          , "justify-content" => "center"
          , "user-select" => "none"
          ]
      ]
      [ text item
      ]


px : Int -> String
px number =
  toString number ++ "px"


getOffset : Model -> Int -> String
getOffset {position, items, drag} index =
  case drag of
    Nothing ->
      translate 0 0

    Just {id, start,current} ->
      if index == id then
        translate (current.x - start.x) (current.y - start.y)
      else
        translate 0 0

translate : Int -> Int -> String
translate x y =
  "translate(" ++ toString x ++ "px , " ++ toString y ++ "px)"


onMouseDown : Int -> Attribute Msg
onMouseDown id =
  on "mousedown" (Json.map (DragStart id) Mouse.position)
```